# MongoDB return sub document as an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query on mongoose

```
const result = await modelProfile.findOne(
    {
      _id: profileId,
    },
    { 'payItems.ACId': 1 }
  );
```

profile sample is

```
{
    "firstName": "ABC",
    "lastName": "DEF",
    "payItems": [
       {
        "ACId": {
            "$oid": "6168825c5d0edbc0b61615db"
        },
        "balance": 0,
        "rate": 0
    }, {
        "ACId": {
            "$oid": "6168825c5d0edbc0b61615dc"
        },
        "balance": 1,
        "rate": 2
    }]
}
```

when I ran it, it returns the following results that is correct:

```
{ payItems: 
   [
     { ACId: ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615db") },
     { ACId: ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615dc") } 
   ] 
}
```

That is correct, is there any way that I can MongoDB that I would like to return it "without keys" something like this (array of Ids)?

```
 [  
    ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615db"),
    ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615dc")
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregation pipeline for this. You can check out [a live demo of this query here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C6fIkN7gS--)

Something like:

```js
const result = await modelProfile.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": profileId
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "payItems": {
        "$push": "$payItems.ACId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "payItems": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Which returns:

```
[
  {
    "payItems": [
      [
        ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615db"),
        ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615dc")
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

## UPDATE

You can check out a [live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5KQXI7keXMV)

### New Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "payItems": {
        "$push": "$payItems.ACId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "payItems": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$payItems"
  }
])
```

### New Results

```
[
  {
    "payItems": [
      ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615db"),
      ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615dc")
    ]
  }
]
```

### Details

This means you will have to do something like this:

```js
const results = await modelProfile.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "payItems": {
        "$push": "$payItems.ACId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "payItems": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$payItems"
  }
]);

results.forEach((result) => {
  // result.payItems has the ids you are looking for
  // If you know you only want the first item in the array
  // just do: 
  // const result = results[0];
  // result.payItems.forEach(item => {...});

  result.payItems.forEach((id) => {
    console.log(id);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, dear @Matt, is there any way to receive only the last nested array, not the two arrays around it? I mean result to be only the following?
[
        ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615db"),
        ObjectId("6168825c5d0edbc0b61615dc")
 ]

Comment: Thanks for your time dear @Matt

Comment: Hey @MehranIshanian I updated my answer with something a little more refined.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you meant at first. Apologies.

Comment: You are very welcome, @MehranIshanian :) If this helped solve your issue, please make sure to make my answer as the accepted answer :) Thank you.